# Regarding loading the phone contacts in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am developing a application in iphone which requires me to load my phone contacts.
how to load my contacts in the application?Is there any API or LIBRARY which allows me do the this.
Kindly suggest me with some solutions.

Regards,
Vijaya

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1).

Comment: No problem - Don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one :)